# Where is Spark catalog metadata stored?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bigdata

Have been trying to get an accurate view of how Spark's catalog API stores the metadata.

I have found some resources, but no answer:

- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Catalog.html
- https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-CatalogImpl.html
- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/catalog/Catalog.html

I see some tutorials that take for granted the existence of Hive Metastore.

- Is Hive Metastore potentially included with Spark distribution?
- Spark cluster can be short-lived, but Hive metastore would obviously need to be long-lived

Apart from the catalog feature, partitioning and sorting features when writing out a DF seem to depend on Hive... So "everyone" seems to take Hive as granted when talking about key Spark features of persisting a DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark becomes aware of Hive MetaStore when it is provided with `hive-site.xml`, which is typically placed under `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. Whenever `enableHiveSupport()` method is used while creating `SparkSession`, Spark finds where and how to 
get connected with Hive metastore. Spark therefore does not explicitly stores hive settings.

Comment: If there's no Hive, and nothing ever calls enableHiveSupport, or creates hive-site.xml, where is the catalog stored, and how do you change that location?